# Nautilus won't connect to server

Tags: gnome, nautilus, sftp

I'm using Nautilus and trying to connect via sftp. When I go to "Other Locations" it shows my other hard drives, but under networks the mouse is just spinning like Nautilus is loading. I have no idea what it's loading.

When I enter my sftp server's IP address, "Connect" is still grayed out like its not done loading. How can I make it connect?

Comment: What happens when you do this on commandline? Are you allowed to sftp with these network disks? Did it ever work? As it stands now this is a rant and not a problem we can address: we need error notices to help you with or commands that we can check for flaws.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same issue. [This forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2361460) solved it for me.

It almost sounds like you have a package missing. Try installing it:

```
sudo apt install gvfs-backends
```

If it says it's already installed, try reinstalling with

```
sudo apt --reinstall install gvfs-backends
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - very helpful. For others, don't forget to open a new Nautilus / file manager window after reinstall to see the changes.